# Symfony 2.7, dynamical role for user versus Mysql Table

Tags: symfony, security

What is the best way to implement such a security, than only several users can edit the "Event" entity.

1) Use Noback advice about dynamical roles:
http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-creating-dynamic-roles-using-roleinterface/

But it is not clear for me how to use these roles. But it is clear how to create them.

2) Create table with users_id, who can edit "Event", and than check in eventEditAction if editing user is in this table for this event ?

What are other ways to permit only for certain users to edit "Event" entity ( /  to forbid for other users to edit ) ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make a (custom) list of users that can edit an event then you should create that list with a many-to-many (User versus Event) relation in the database. Then you can use a Voter to check User Permissions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Comment: Thank you. Is it a good practice, instead of voter and MtoM table, assign an event id to User field type Array "editEvents" - kind of role type field. When set the session variable according this "editEvents" with event id list, which user can edit - "SES_event_id". Than check in template if event_id is in SES_event_id and for such a users display "event edit" links. Also double check in edit action, if User "editEvents" field contains the event id ?

Comment: I don't like array field types in the database because you can not select records of the array items like you do for normal database rows. Why do you want to use sessions? Do you realize that it are not only the links that you need to disable? you have to secure the controllers too...